# Need to perform a re-runnable t-sql script that creates a column (if not existant) and then perform some actions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using sql server 2005

the idea is to create a column, update the values to 0, make it not nullable then, and recreate an existing PK adding it to the list
so far i've got this :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Division')
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD Division int NULL
   UPDATE MyTable SET Division = 0
   ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN Division int NOT NULL

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC,
        [OfferCode] ASC,
        [StationCode] ASC,
        [Market] ASC,
        [Division] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]   

END
```

The problem is that i need a "GO" statement so that the new column is created, otherwise i get an error when trying to update the values to 0. If i put a "GO" statement, then the if clause doesn't work (because the column now exists). i was thinking of putting that status to a variable like @ColumnWasCreated, but the "GO" statement is like starting a whole new script, and the variable's value is lost
any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

Instead of `GO`, try a `TRANSACTION` that encompasses the `ADD COLUMN`; then commit it and see if you can `UPDATE`.

**OPTION 2**

Try setting a default value constraint when you `ADD COLUMN`, this way, you won't have to `UPDATE` or `ALTER` to not allow `nulls`.

Comment: Option 2 worked perfectly (and no need to create transactions). 

ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD Division int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

thanks!

Comment: oops, just realised. i don't want a default value for the column. is there a way to remove it easily afterwards? (it's a constraint)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT`; here's the catch: you need the constraint name which is auto-generated if you create it with the `TABLE CREATE` command. So you'll need a query to pull the constraint from the `sys` data tables.

Comment: @Daniel, http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/16/sql-server-2005-list-all-the-constraint-of-database-find-primary-key-and-foreign-key-constraint-in-database/